# Kickstart not installing X on rhel 7.2

Tags: rhel, system-installation, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I'm trying to use kickstart and install a RHEL 7.2 system with a GUI. In  my ks.cfg file I have specified these options to achieve a system that boots with X enabled.

```
%packages --ignoremissing
@Server with GUI
@GNOME Desktop
@X Window System
@Development and Creative Workstation
@Graphical Administration Tools
@Fonts
%end
%post
/bin/systemctl set-default graphical.target
%end
```

The package selections for X were taken from the RHEL page here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5238

For some reason, my system boots into text only mode. However, If I check the target its set to "graphical-target". There is no mention of any problems in the logs. When I do a "yum grouplist" surely enough these packages do not show up as "Installed" My first thought is that maybe its trying to pull these down from the internet and failing because its not a subscribed system but it *should* be pulling from the local share on the ftp/pxe server. The ksvalidator tools finds no problems with my kickstart file. I'm stumped.

Comment: When I use the [Kickstart Generator](https://access.redhat.com/labs/kickstartconfig/) it suggests `@x11`; does that work any better?

Comment: yea, that would probably work since I just found out its case sensitive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution --

Seems that kickstart/anaconda does not like uppercase and spaces. I changed to this config below and it worked. Not sure why ksvalidator does not pick up on that if the case or syntax is a problem. Anyway, problem solved. HTH someone else.

```
%packages --ignoremissing
@^graphical-server-environment
@base
@core 
@gnome-desktop
@x-window-system 
@development-and-creative-workstation
@graphical-administration-tools
@fonts 
@server-with-gui
%end
```

The resulting config above yields an anaconda-ks.cfg file in /root of the newly installed system that looks like the following.

```
%packages --ignoremissing
@^graphical-server-environment
@base
@core
@desktop-debugging
@development-and-creative-workstation
@dial-up
@fonts
@gnome-desktop
@graphical-administration-tools
@guest-agents
@guest-desktop-agents
@input-methods
@internet-browser
@multimedia
@print-client
@server-with-gui
@x-window-system
@x11
```